# Known versions of ruby - rvm list known

Tags: ruby, rvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting versions of ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974479/deleting-versions-of-ruby)

I'm trying to uninstall a single version of ruby. The second in this list:

```
which -a ruby
/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/ruby
/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/bin/ruby
```

However, when I run:

```
rvm remove
```

I get:

```
Really? remove all? See "rvm list known" and limit the selection to something more sane please :)
```

So, running:

```
rvm list known
```

shows a whole list of versions. However, none of these is the one I want to delete, i.e. /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/bin/ruby

E.g.

```
# MRI Rubies
[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
[ruby-]1.8.7[-p358]
[ruby-]1.8.7-head
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
[ruby-]1.9.2-p180
[ruby-]1.9.2-p290
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p318]
[ruby-]1.9.2-head
[ruby-]1.9.3-preview1
[ruby-]1.9.3-rc1
[ruby-]1.9.3-p0
[ruby-]1.9.3[-p125]
[ruby-]1.9.3-head
ruby-head

# GoRuby
goruby

# TheCodeShop - MRI experimental patches
tcs

# JRuby
jruby-1.2.0
jruby-1.3.1
jruby-1.4.0
jruby-1.6.5
jruby-1.6.5.1
jruby-1.6.6
jruby[-1.6.7]
jruby-head

# Rubinius
rbx-1.0.1
rbx-1.1.1
rbx-1.2.3
rbx-1.2.4
rbx[-head]
rbx-2.0.testing

# Ruby Enterprise Edition
ree-1.8.6
ree[-1.8.7][-2012.02]

# Kiji
kiji

# MagLev
maglev[-head]
maglev-1.0.0

# Mac OS X Snow Leopard Or Newer
macruby[-0.10]
macruby-nightly
macruby-head

# IronRuby -- Not implemented yet.
ironruby-0.9.3
ironruby-1.0-rc2
ironruby-head
```

Comment: This is an extension of your previous question. Don't create a new question on the same topic, instead, append the new information to your previous question so we can track progress.

Answer (score 4):

You lack knowledge of rvm:

```
$ rvm list
...
=* ruby-1.9.3-p327 [ x86_64 ]
...

$ rvm alias list
default => ruby-1.9.3-p327
```

now what is in the list can be removed:

```
$ rvm remove 1.9.3
```

and what is an alias has to be removed as alias:

```
$ rvm alias delete default
```

all this information is available at rvm site => https://rvm.io

Comment: I was just following the instructions in the output, i.e.: "Really? remove all? See "rvm list known" and limit the selection to something more sane please :)"

Comment: fixed https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/commit/fe2a0bbda22349472b59f2d5021710cb924651bb

Answer (score 0):

Aha - figured it out:

```
rvm uninstall all
```

Interestingly, this deletes all versions **apart** from the one I wanted to delete!

```
which -a ruby
/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/bin/ruby
```